# console.log not working in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

I've been using WebStorm's debugger for over a year with no problem. But now suddenly `console.log` no longer outputs to WebStorm's console window.

Has anyone ever run into this?

Some clues:

- I'm using the Chrome plugin for debugging.
- Debugging is local (i.e. `localhost`)
- Breakpoints work fine
- The browser's debugging console gets the console.log statement fine
- I'm using Windows 7

Comment: Please state your IDE and Chrome versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console logging got broken recently with Chrome API update. If you are using Chrome 54+, please try upgrading to 2016.3 EAP (release is coming soon) - the issue is fixed there